# IntelliJ IDEA 15.0.3 does not showing spring MVC template on project creation

Tags: java, spring-mvc, intellij-idea

I am running IntelliJ IDEA 15.0.3 .I tried to create spring mvc project 
**File->New->Projects**

[image]

After clicking next button i get following page
[image]

I do not find springMVC project template which was found in intellij 14 and previous versions.

I checked spring plugins installed but dont know how to show or integrate Spring MVC project template in IntelliJ IDEA 15.0.3. Please help guys.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of template, you can do it all manually.

Firstly, download projects named Chapter 12 from this url:
http://www.wrox.com/WileyCDA/WroxTitle/Professional-Java-for-Web-Applications.productCd-1118656466,descCd-DOWNLOAD.html

Then open Spring-Hybrid-Config under IntelliJ folder and just look at project resources, files, classes etc. 
Watch this video: 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jAecXzeBoDE

Afterward copy files from downloaded project to the maven project that you created by watching this video. I did as I said so my project works well.   Make sure that your project’s Facets and Artifacts as same as downloaded project.

Comment: You might want to revise your answer, but before you do, please read [How do I write a good answer?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Try to approach your answer from this point of view: Is my answer self-contained? Does it answer the question fully, correctly, and without referring to external sites?

Comment: Actually i am wondering about spring mvc template in intellij not maven MVC to build projects

Comment: Syed, if you pay attention closely to spring mvc template you will see that it is maven project just filled eligible files relate to spring mvc. It seems that spring mvc template also made as I suggested to you. If you do as I said you would do exactly same as spring mvc template in IntelliJ 14 version.

Comment: But i do want to integrate that project template as in intellij as it is 14.0.1 version as every time i open a project i creates a working template

Comment: Create once as I said then save it as template then reuse it in every project creation.